# Send variable to subfunction without sending to main object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I would like to create an Object like this:

```
Object = function () {
    this.Subfunction = function (Data) {
        alert('Data');
    }
}
```

And be able to call it from outside of the object, like this:

```
var Object = new Object();
Object.Subfunction(Data);
```

It's really inconvenient to have to send `Data` through `Object` every time I want to run anything in the `Object`.

Comment: That will work fine.  What is your question?

Comment: It doesn't work for me: http://jsfiddle.net/3EpSy/

Comment: @Jamil You need to create `Data` - You're currently passing an undefined variable.

Comment: `ReferenceError: Data is not defined` Look in the error console and debug your code.  Also, don't create anything named `Object`.

Comment: Try this one: http://jsfiddle.net/SML3D/1/

Comment: Here check this: http://jsfiddle.net/75raE/

Comment: I noticed just recently. Is there any reason it wouldn't send an array?

Comment: @Jamil Nope, it should work as well.

Comment: Weird. I've been having a problem where if I send it to the subfunction it doesn't work, but if I send it to the main object, it works... I suppose I'll keep looking into it.

Comment: Just make a fiddle and we'll help you out.

Comment: @Jamil: Use a Javascript debugger to find your actual problem.

Comment: @SLaks Well, this problem happened twice so I figured I'd ask about it. For the first, it worked well enough so I just sent the value through the object. I figured out the current problem. Apparently it had to do with something related but not exactly that (passing a variable through a function into another function). If I run into it again, I'll definitely bring it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe moving this *function* to the *prototype* would be better suited for you

```
MyObject = function () {};
MyObject.prototype.subFunction = function (data) {console.log('Data', data);};

// this still works
var myObject = new MyObject();
myObject.subFunction('foo');

// this also works
MyObject.prototype.subFunction('bar');
```

Note in the *bar* example, you didn't need to use `new`, however that time it would not be instance specific (`this` is set to the *prototype* unless context is chosen manually).

Comment: Even through this isn't the simplest answer, it does explain the `.prototype` very clearly, so I think it's the most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

> It's really inconvenient to have to send Data through Object every
>   time I want to run anything in the Object

That's the beauty of object-oriented programming. Objects can hold data and have behaviours attached to them. If you want to avoid passing `data` all the time, you can use the `constructor` function to initialize and store `data` as a member of your newly created instance.

For example:

```
function SomeObject(data) {
    this.data = data; //store data
}

SomeObject.prototype.doSomething = function () {
    console.log(this.data); //use data
};

var o = new SomeObject('some data as string');

o.doSomething(); //no need to pass data anymore
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps what you meant to do is work with the parameter that was passed:

```
Object = function () {
    this.Subfunction = function (Data) {
        alert(Data);
    }
};

var test= "Hello world !";
var Object = new Object();
Object.Subfunction(test);
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3EpSy/